# Creating table from json in javascript using jquery for any field

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I so far can view the json response. Now I wanted to convert them to tables. I am using the following code to parse data about weather of cities. I am trying to use the following code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function goTo() {
            $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?key=api&format=json&q=" + link_id.value, function(result, status, jqXHR) {
                    var myList = (jqXHR.responseText);
                    var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList);

                    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
                        var row$ = $('<tr/>');
                        for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {
                            var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];

                            if (cellValue == null) {
                                cellValue = "";
                            }

                            row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
                        }
                        $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
                    }
                }
            );}


        function addAllColumnHeaders(myList) {
            var columnSet = [];
            var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

            for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
                var rowHash = myList[i];
                for (var key in rowHash) {
                    if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {
                        columnSet.push(key);
                        headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
                    }
                }
            }
            $("#excelDataTable").append(headerTr$);

            return columnSet;
        }​
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <h2> Search box </h2>
    <input type='text' id='link_id'>
    <input type='button' id='link' value='Search' onClick='goTo()'>
    <table id="excelDataTable" border="1" />

    <div></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I got the following result:

[image]

And in chrome, i can't even view that

Comment: first convert myList to a json object like this var jsonList = $.parseJSON(myList); and then iterate through the object and create your table

Comment: Hi, I updated the description. I tried a new bit of code.

Comment: I get the following error in both cases:
`ReferenceError: goTo is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (http://null.jsbin.com/runner:1:1874)`

Comment: try putting the value of myList in the console and see how the JSON is received. the json value is completely different. they're all unique values. try going from there or use a jquery plugin

Comment: sorry, i found some syntax errors. I edited my description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response I'm getting is an object not an array. Process the response as an object.

```js
function goTo() {
  $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?key=api&format=json&q=" + link_id.value, function(result, status, jqXHR) {
    var myList = (jqXHR.responseText);
    myList = JSON.parse(myList);
    console.log(myList);
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in myList) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
    addAllColumnHeaders(myList, keys);
    var row$ = $('<tr/>');
    
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      
      var key = keys[i];
      var cellValue = myList[key];

      if (cellValue == null) {
        cellValue = "";
      } else if (typeof cellValue == "object") {
        cellValue = JSON.stringify(cellValue);
      }

      row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
    }
    
    $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
  });
}


function addAllColumnHeaders(myList, keys) {

  var columnSet = [];
  var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
  }
  $("#excelDataTable").append(headerTr$);

  return columnSet;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2> Search box </h2>
<input type='text' id='link_id'>
<input type='button' id='link' value='Search' onClick='goTo()'>
<table id="excelDataTable" border="1" />

<div></div>
```

Comment: Hi, Everytime i run a new query a new table gets added instead. How might I clear the existing table?

Comment: @DavidWalsh before addAllColumnHeaders clear the html with $("#excelDataTable").html("");